# I would like to have my DataGrid read the row ID and populate row values in a new window

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

```
namespace CaseManagementSystem
```

{

```
public partial class DataGrid_HBD : UserControl
{

    public DataGrid_HBD()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // 2 Seconds Timer before connecting to the Database.
        // This improves UI rendering on button click
        DataGrid_Data();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loading Data Grid
    /// </summary>
    public void DataGrid_Data()
    {
        // 2 second delay before loading DataGrid
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3) };
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();

            // Attemption to connect to SQL Server database and populate DataGrid with database tables. 
            try
            {
                string connectionString = ("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [hb_Disputes].[DSP_ID], [hb_disputes].[ACCOUNT], [hb_disputes].[CUST_NAME],[hb_disputes].[PREM_ADDR], [hb_status].[Status], [hb_disputes].[OPENED], [hb_disputes].[DEADLINE], [hb_rpttype].[ReportType], [hb_ratetype].[RateType] FROM [hb_disputes] LEFT JOIN [hb_status] ON [hb_disputes].[STATUS] = [hb_status].[STSID] LEFT JOIN [hb_rpttype] ON [hb_disputes].[RPTTYPE] = [hb_rpttype].[RPTID] LEFT JOIN [hb_ratetype] ON [hb_disputes].[REV_CLS] = [hb_ratetype].[RTID]", connection);
                connection.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                connection.Close();

                dtGrid.DataContext = dt;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Database connection is not available at this time. Please contact your database administrator ");
            }

        };
    }

    private void dtGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // User double clicks on DataGrid Row
        // Open new Window
        // Populate selected textboxes with selected datarow
        DataGrid gd = (DataGrid)sender;
        DataRowView row_selected = gd.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        var windowToOpen = new Window1();

        if(gd !=null )
        {
            windowToOpen.txt_RowRecrd.Text = row_selected["DSP_ID"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_acctnumber.Text = row_selected["ACCOUNT"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_custname.Text = row_selected["CUST_NAME"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_address.Text = row_selected["PREM_ADDR"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_opened.Text = row_selected["OPENED"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_deadline.Text = row_selected["DEADLINE"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.txt_revcls.Text = row_selected["RateType"].ToString();
            windowToOpen.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Currently, when the user double clicks on the Datagrid row I have some code written take ONLY the columns displayed in the data table and populate them in the respective textboxes.

I would like to have limited information on the data gride and show the entire row of data when the user double clicks placed in their textboxes and comboboxes.

I think I would need some code to have my "Windows1" read the DSP_ID and populate the respective textboxes and comboboxes with the information in that row.
[image: Screenshot of New Window with populated Information]

Answer (score 0):

Even if a datagrid isn't showing a particular column the data is still available from the underlying row (A DataRowView class has a `.Row` that gives the underlying DataRow) via the DataRowView. If you want more data in your `dt` add the columns to the select query. If you want less data to show in the grid cull the columns the grid shows. Pass the grid row's DataRowView to the new window that opens and the textboxes can pull the extra info even though it wasn't visible in the grid.